# Is Docker image updated incrementally in production environment

Tags: docker

Lets say we have docker image instance running in production environment. The image contains Linux OS and application jar file. As part of a patch release there are some changes in some classes in application jar. Can these changes be updated incrementally in production or we need to replace entire image? If we can create an increment and update it, what are the commands to do these operations.

In large production environment where there are huge number of docker instances running and needs patching, it will be over head to move entire image rather than a increment/delta.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the *change and commit* strategy for docker images in production environments. Simply because at the end you cannot exactly reproduce the way changes have been made to the images. You can only see the diffs.

I would build images in a build environment (e.g. Jenkins) by using `Dockerfile`s. Especially - as you mentioned JAR files - when you use [maven](http://maven.apache.org) to build your Java application you could also generate a docker image very easily within the same build using the [docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin). So you would always be able by reproduce an image within your build environment.

Then when it comes to the deployment phase where you need to deploy to dozens of servers you would not do it manually of course. You would automate that step.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [FAQ](https://docs.docker.com/engine/faq/), you can incrementally update images, similar to a git pull.

> Versioning. Docker includes git-like capabilities for tracking successive versions of a container, inspecting the diff between versions, committing new versions, rolling back etc. The history also includes how a container was assembled and by whom, so you get full traceability from the production server all the way back to the upstream developer. Docker also implements incremental uploads and downloads, similar to git pull, so new versions of a container can be transferred by only sending diffs.

As far as how to do this, I would think the [docker pull](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/) command would be the way to go, as it skips already downloaded layers and only gets the new ones.